# Azure VNET to VNET to site to site VPN connectivity

Tags: azure, vpn, vnet, onpremises-gateway

Scenario.

We have a site 2 site VPN from ON PREM to Azure VNET (with a vnet gateway) in a specific rg.
lets call the VNET with the VPN connection for: vnet-vpn

Then we have a VNET in another Resourcegroup in Azure (Same subscription as vnet-vpn) lets call it vnet-a

I need services in vnet-a to be able to call on prem systems by proxying thru the vnet-vpn and that way gaining access to the on-prem network.

I can:

- create a connection between the 2 vnets in Azure (vnet-vpn, vnet-a) by using peering.Tested by letting services from each vnet communicate directly.
- call on prem services from applications placed in the vnet-vpn.

I CANNOT:

- access on-prem systems from vnet-a.

I cannot find any documentation that explicitly describes this scenario and and to set it up.
Can someone please help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit) which resembles the scenario you are trying out. You need to enable gateway transit on your peered VNET in order to establish connectivity with your on-prem systems.

Answer (score 0):

More info on current config could be used to answer this, but here are a couple of ideas:

- Make sure Gateway Transit is enabled inside the peering configuration between `vnet-vpn` and `vnet-a`
- Make sure that `vnet-a` IP range is included in your Azure VPN and also OnPrem VPN configuration

  - Alternatively, NAT your `vnet-a` addresses into some range which is acceptable for your OnPrem VPN. Please be aware that `NAT rules` feature is only Preview on Azure Virtual Network Gateway. You either have to take the risk of using a preview feature (fine for non-production workloads), or implement your own NAT appliance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible is too late, however if anyone came across this post with the same issue, this is a solution:

Scenario:

OnPrem<----S2S----->Az Vnet-A

You want direct access from OnPrem Site to another Azure VNET, let's call it Vnet-B using the existing setup between OnPrem an Vnet-A.

Solution:

- Create a vnet peering between the 2 VNETs, make sure that the gateway transit is enabled on Vnet-A side (the VNET that has the Gateway VPN configuration) --> you can use the article shared in the comments  above
- the peering will ensure connectivity between Vnet-A and Vnet-B, however just doing this step will not allow connectivity from OnPrem to Vnet-B
- to have direct access from OnPrem to Vnet-B you also have to create UDR on both VNETs
- create a RouteTable-A and connect it to a Vnet-A subnet, create a route, this route will say: when the traffic leaves this subnet it will be redirect to Address Prefix [a subnet in Vnet-B], and the NextHop is None (dropped by default)
- create a RouteTable-B, connect it to a subnet in Vnet-B, create a route, this route will say: when the traffic leaves this subnet it will be redirect to the Address Prefix of the Vnet-A Gateway Subnet and the NextHop is Virtual Network Gateway

And that's all by creating a peering with Gateway Transit enabled on the Vnet that is connected the the Azure Gateway VPN, and creating the Routes with the settings I mentioned earlier you will have direct access from OnPrem to Vnet-B also.

Regards